# How safe is Apache's Commons StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml function to prevent XSS

Tags: xss

I am using escapeXML StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml to prevent XSS in my Java application. But I am wondering if it resolves XSS to the fullest.

I have tried some XSS attack vectors, and escapeXml seems to work fine.

Basically most of the examples I tried included **<** , **>** etc.
Are there any attack vectors which would make escapeXml fail ?

Comment: You could try the techniques described on https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet against it.

Comment: Sometimes escaping is not enough, give this a quick read: https://www.synopsys.com/blogs/software-security/fixing-cross-site-scripting-developers-guide/